# repeating a vector many times without repmat MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a vector with very large size in column format, I want to repeat this vector multiple times. the simple method that works for small arrays is `repmat` but I am running out of memory. I used `bsxfun` but still no success, MATLAB gives me an error of memory for using `ones`. any idea how to do that?

Here is the simple code (just for demonstration):

```
 t=linspace(0,1000,89759)';

 tt=repmat(t,1,length(t));
```

or using bsxfun:

```
 tt=bsxfun(@times,t, ones(length(t),length(t)));
```

Comment: The problem is not repeating, it is handling such a big amount of data. Why you need such a suge repetition? there is a way to work with your data without repeting them?

Comment: I am trying to find the intersecting points of two curves ... each curves contain very large amount of data ... I had the idea of breaking the data into smaller pieces but that makes even a bigger mess ...

Comment: the code that I use is here: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections)

the code is written really nicely but for large array it gives memory error

Comment: maybe then you should sample less points on the curves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is simply too much data, it does not have to do with the repmat function itself. To verify that it is too much data, you can simply try creating a matrix of ones of that size with a clear workspace to reproduce the error. On my system, I get this error:

```
>> clear
>> a = ones(89759,89759)
Error using ones
Requested 89759x89759 (60.0GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than
this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference
panel for more information.
```

So you fundamentally need to reduce the amount of data you are handling.

Also, I should note that plots will hold onto references to the data, so even if you try plotting this "in chunks", then you will still run into the same problem. So again, you fundamentally need to reduce the amount of data you are handling.

Comment: okay I approached the problem in a different way and could reduce the dimension significantly ... thanks for help